# Interactive reminder options not visible in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have implemented interactive reminders for local notifications. But those interactive options are visible only when device is unlocked and user pulled down the reminders just after receiving. The first image show just after receiving local notification.

[image: Just after receiving]

If you swipe it left or right nothing happen. But if you pull down, then you can see the two interactive options. Just like in the second image.

[image]

**(Q1.)** Actually, my first question is why it just show only two options while I have declared three interactive options?

Below is my related code for that.

```
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
notificationCategory.identifier = mutableUserNotificationCategoryId;
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1, notificationAction2, notificationAction3] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1, notificationAction2, notificationAction3] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];

UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

**(Q2.)** My second question is, why we can't see interactive options when user swipe the notification in any other stage. (Ex. notification shows under notification center) Please see my next images that I've uploaded.

[image] [image]

Comment: If its a 3D-touch enabled device, notification actions are available on 3D-touch.

Answer (score 0):

If using `UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal` then notification alert will display no more than 2 custom actions for this context. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiusernotificationactioncontext/uiusernotificationactioncontextminimal)

On 3D-touch-enabled devices, notification alert actions are available when pulling down the alert or using the 3d-touch gesture. The way you want to view custom actions is available for non 3d-touch devices.

Comment: I've removed the `UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal` line but kept three options for default context. But even then, it just show me only last two options.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm testing this on iPhone 6S with OS version 10.3.2 with only a single notification. So, I think it should have enough space to show all three options.